# Parce data, Python

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am interesting in Python . I need to parse data from Fred (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A191RI1A225NBEA) . So, I need to ask Python to go on this website and then click "Download" button and then click "CSV(data)" button and save this data in Python . Actually, a have a great problem with this task, I tried using from selenium:

```
selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/davidabramyan/Downloads/chromedriver 3')
browser = browser.get('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A191RI1A225NBEA')
elm = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Download')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
elm.click()
```

## And using BeautifulSoup:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
return response.read()

def parse(html):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('span', class_='pull-right col-xs-1')
rows = table.find('fg-download-menu')
print(table.prettify())

def main():
parse(get_html('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A191RI1A225NBEA#0'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

But it doesn't work . I think Beautifulsoup is better, but there I can't really understand how to do it . Could you help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use BeautifulSoup because download url for "CSV (data)" is generated by ajax

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/davidabramyan/Downloads/chromedriver 3')
# make sure above is chromedriver executable path not directory
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A191RI1A225NBEA')

dlButton = browser.find_element_by_id("download-button")
dlButton.click()
wait.until(lambda driver: browser.execute_script("return $('#download-data-csv').attr('href') != '#'"))
dlButton = browser.find_element_by_id("download-data-csv")
dlButton.click()

# get url to download with python
# csv_download_url = dlButton.get_attribute('href')
# csv_file = urllib2.urlopen(download)
# ....
```

Comment: Yeah! It's works! Thank you! One more question: so if it is ajax it is impossible to parse data? How could I understand that this is ajax (sorry for stupid questions) @ewwink

Comment: and one more, by this code I can install file from the link, but how can automatically import in the Python, if I don't know the name of downloading file?

Comment: it possible but not easy with bs4, to know it set by ajax just run in browser console `$('#download-data-csv').attr('href')` it will give you `#` as url, now click Download button then run again previous command and it will give you `"/graph/fredgraph.csv?bgcolor.....`

Comment: if you don't want to download, get the url from `$('#download-data-csv').attr('href')` and download it with python

Comment: updated the code, to get csv download url for used in python